# redefinition of classes error in c++

Tags: c++, numerical-methods

I searched through some of the other pages with this same error, but my code does not have any of their issues that I can find.

I have a base class named QBase defined in quadrature.h:

```
#ifndef SRC_QUADRATURE_H_
#define SRC_QUADRATURE_H_

#include "enum_order.h"
#include "enum_quadrature_type.h"
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class QBase
{
    protected:

        QBase (const Order _order=INVALID_ORDER);

    public:

        virtual ~QBase() {}

        virtual QuadratureType type() const = 0;

        static std::unique_ptr<QBase> build (const QuadratureType qt, const Order order=INVALID_ORDER);

        const std::vector<double> & get_points() const { return _points; }
        const std::vector<double> & get_weights() const { return _weights; }
        std::vector<double> & get_points() { return _points; }
        std::vector<double> & get_weights() { return _weights; }

    protected:

        const Order _order;

        std::vector<double> _points;
        std::vector<double> _weights;
};

#endif /* SRC_QUADRATURE_H */
```

I derive a class QGaussLegendre by QBase definded in gauss_legendre.h

```
#ifndef SRC_QUADRATURE_GAUSSLEGENDRE_H_
#define SRC_QUADRATURE_GAUSSLEGENDRE_H_

#include "quadrature.h"

class QGaussLegendre : public QBase
{
    public: 

         QGaussLegendre (const Order _order=INVALID_ORDER) : QBase (_order){}

         ~QGaussLegendre (){}

         virtual QuadratureType type() { return QGAUSSLEGENDRE; }
};

#endif /* SRC_QUADRATURE_GAUSSLEGENDRE_H_ */
```

In the main file I use the build() member function to get points and weights as follows

```
const Order order = ddp.order;
const QuadratureType qt = ddp.qt;

static std::unique_ptr<QBase> qr(QBase::build(qt,order));

const std::vector<double>& points = qr->get_points();
const std::vector<double>& weights = qr->get_weights();
```

I don't have any problem till here. Now, the points and weights are defined in the file legendre_gauss.cxx

```
#include "gauss_legendre.h"

QGaussLegendre::QGaussLegendre(const Order order)
{

    switch(order)
    {

       case CONSTANT:
       case FIRST:
       {
           _points.resize (1);
           _weights.resize(1);

           _points[0](0)  = 0.;

           _weights[0]= 2.;
        }
     }
}
```

When I compile this last file I get the error:

```
/home/matteo/flux/gauss_legendre.cxx:13:1: 
error: redefinition of ‘QGaussLegendre::QGaussLegendre(qenum::Order)’
 QGaussLegendre::QGaussLegendre(const Order order)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/matteo/flux/gauss_legendre.cxx:8:0:
/home/matteo/flux/gauss_legendre.h:25:3: 
note: ‘QGaussLegendre::QGaussLegendre(qenum::Order)’ previously 
defined here
 QGaussLegendre (const Order _order=INVALID_ORDER) : QBase (_order)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Can I do to solve the problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well it is previously defined there. Define it once only and your problem is solved.

Comment: As the error message says, you have defined `QGaussLegendre::QGaussLegendre` two times. Remove one of them, preferably the empty one in `gauss_legendre.h:25`.

Comment: Did you read the error? You are re-defining your constructor of .`QGaussLegendre`. **Both** the header, and .cpp file contains a definition of it.

Comment: Defined in two different ways, I'm guessing both definitions need to be combined in the cpp file.

Answer (score 3):

> redefinition of classes error

That's not an error about redefinition of a class. That is an error about redefinition of a function. In particular, redefinition of the function `QGaussLegendre::QGaussLegendre(const Order order)` which is the contsructor of class `QGaussLegendre`.

You've defined it first here in `quadrature.h`:

```
QGaussLegendre (const Order _order=INVALID_ORDER) : QBase (_order){}
```

And second time in `legendre_gauss.cxx`:

```
QGaussLegendre::QGaussLegendre(const Order order)
{
```

> Can I do to solve the problem?

Solution is to define the function exactly once.

Comment: So, I can define the constructor only in legendre_gauss.cxx. But in this case I get <error: prototype for ‘QGaussLegendre::QGaussLegendre(qenum::Order)’ does not match any in class ‘QGaussLegendre’>

Comment: @Matteo did you declare the constructor in the class definition?

Comment: In gauss_legendre.h I write <class QGaussLegendre : public QBase{public:QGaussLegendre(); etc...}>

Comment: @Matteo so, you've declared the function `QGaussLegendre()`, but you haven't declared `QGaussLegendre(Order)` which is what you try to define? There's your problem.